# Extract native libs from prebuilt apk file using Android.mk

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-install-apk, android-native-library, android-make

I have an APK file with the bundled native libs. When I install them using adb the libraries are correctly created at <path-to_package>/lib/, But I have to integrate my apk to the build system along with the Android.mk file. What I need to add in the make to get the libs extracted on to the target

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by _"integrate my apk to the build system along with the Android.mk file"_. How did you build the libraries in the first place?

Comment: I got the libs from third party. And now I have apk, I just need to write the makefile which copies the apk and native libs on the target.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts

Answer (score 2):

You can find an example in AOSP, e.g. in `external/chromium-webview` project:

- using `Android.mk` (outdated): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/chromium-webview/+/refs/heads/android10-d4-release/Android.mk
- using `Android.bp`: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/chromium-webview/+/refs/heads/master/Android.bp.

Also some related topics were already discussed on SO:

- [How do I add APKs in an AOSP build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579827/how-do-i-add-apks-in-an-aosp-build?lq=1)
- [When are the APKs in system/app being installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64689472/when-are-the-apks-in-system-app-being-installed)

Comment: This will not extract the libs into lib/abi folder.. Even I checked chromium-webview on the target. It just contains apk not lib/abi

Comment: Yes because they are packed into APK archive, if you want to see them physically e.g. via ```adb shell``` you need to set ```android:extractNativeLibs="true"``` in ```AndroidManifest.xml/application```, it is already discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63219377/where-to-put-c-so-library-needed-for-my-android-application

Comment: Yes, I have added 'extractNativeLibs=true', But does not help. But when I install the app manually via adb it creates the libs at lib/abi.

Comment: Also I need path of these libs in my application, is there a way to get the path of these libs embedded in apk itself?

Comment: ```String pluginDir = new File(getPackageCodePath()).getParent() + "/lib/" + convertABItoLibDir(Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS[0]);```

Comment: ```convertABItoLibDir``` does matching between ABI name and lib directory name, because they don't always fully match, e.g.  ABI "arm64-v8a" corresponds to "arm64" lib folder.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have extracted the libs manually and using them as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64735430/adding-pre-built-apk-vpn-in-aosp-crashes But I try considering your suggestion embedded libs usage

Answer (score 0):

- If you have libraries then copy libraries and create a folder in aosp_source/external/yourlibfolder and paste your libraries there.
- Go to build/target/product and write this code in your relevant make
  file(e.g handhel_system.mk) for each of library. Replace yourlibname with each library name

```
external/yourlibfolder/yourlibname.so:system/lib/yourlibname.so \
external/yourlibfolder/yourlibname.so:system/lib64/yourlibname.so \
```

- It will add app dependent libraries in AOSP. Now when you add your
  Pre-built apk in AOSP it will work

Create a folder in packages/app/yourappfolder and paste APK and make file there

**This should be your make file**

```
# Adding Apk as system app in AOSP
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := Appname # It should be your apk name, and folder name should also be same 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_MODULE).apk
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .apk
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Comment: Cant I add the shared libs in the APK make file?

Comment: You can mention them in apk make file like this ```LOCAL_PREBUILT_JNI_LIBS := \
  @lib/arm/yourlib1.so \
  @lib/arm/yourlib2.so \ ```